Correct statements about partially conserved dilatation current (PCDC)
We know that renormalization introduces an explicit mass scale in quantum field theory, therefore Ward identity for broken scale symmetry has anomalous term. So usual statement of partially conserved dilatation current (PCDC) is not a right statement. Is there correct statement about PCDC in literature incorporating the anomaly at quantum level?
Given below is review about PCDC[1]:
consider a scalar field $\chi$, which transforms linearly under scale transformation,
\begin{equation}
    \alpha : \chi(x) \mapsto \chi'(x')= e^{-\alpha} \chi(x)
\end{equation}
Note that I have used active transformation of field with $x \to e^\alpha x$, for example.
We define a new field $\sigma(x)$,
\begin{equation}
    \chi = \frac{1}{f} e^{f \sigma} \tag{3.2.39}
\end{equation}
where $f$ is a constant.  Therefore $\sigma$ field transforms in non-linear way under scale transformation --
\begin{align}
\sigma(x) &\to \sigma'(x) \nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{f} \log\left(f \chi'(x) \right) \nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{f}  \log\left(f e^{-\alpha}\chi \left(e^{-\alpha} x\right) \right) \nonumber \\
&= - \frac{\alpha}{f} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{f}  \log\left(f \chi \left(e^{-\alpha} x\right) \right)}_{\sigma\left(e^{-\alpha} x\right)}
\end{align}
infinitesimally, the transformation of $\sigma(x)$ field is given as --
\begin{align}
    \delta \sigma(x) &:= \sigma'(x) - \sigma(x) \nonumber\\
    &= -\alpha\left(\frac{1}{f} + x\cdot \partial \sigma\right) + O(\alpha^2)
\end{align}
We can make any Lagrangian into scale invariant Lagrangian by multiplying scale breaking parts by appropriate powers of $e^{f \sigma}$ and adding free kinetic term for $\chi$-field.
For example, consider the following scalar-fermion theory in four space-time dimensions,
\begin{align}
 \mathcal{L} &= \color{green}{\mathcal L_S} + \color{red}{\mathcal L'_B} + \color{blue}{\mathcal L_\chi} \nonumber\\
 &= \color{green}{\frac12(\partial \varphi)^2 + i\bar{\psi}\gamma\cdot \partial \psi +  g_0 \bar{\psi}\gamma_5\psi \varphi - \frac{\lambda_0}{4!}\varphi^4} \nonumber\\
 & \quad  \color{red}{-m_0 \bar{\psi} \psi} \color{purple}{e^{ f \sigma}}  \color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}\mu_0^2\varphi^2}\color{purple}{e^{2f\sigma}} \nonumber\\
 & \quad \color{blue}{+ \frac{1}{2} (\partial \chi)^2}
 \end{align}
for the above transformations, the Lagrangian density transform as:
\begin{align}
 \delta_\alpha \mathcal{L} &= -\alpha(4 + x\cdot\partial)\mathcal{L}
 \end{align}
In above Lagrangian, $\sigma$ is the only massless field; it is the goldstone boson of scale invariance -- dilaton. We can choose scale symmetry breaking term such that the divergence of scale current is proportional to $\sigma-$field.
Consider the following scale-breaking term in the Lagrangian,
\begin{equation}
     \mathcal{L}_B = -\frac{m_{\sigma}^2}{16 f^2} \left(e^{4f\sigma(x)}-4f\sigma(x) - 1\right) \tag{3.2.44}
\end{equation}
under infinitesimal scale transformation, the change in Lagrangian,
\begin{align}
     \delta_{\alpha} \mathcal{L}_B &= -\alpha \left[- \frac{m_\sigma^2}{16 f^2} 4f \left(e^{4f \sigma(x)}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{f} + x\cdot \partial \sigma\right) \right]\nonumber\\
     &= -\alpha\left[ (4 + x\cdot \partial)\mathcal{L}_B - \frac{m_\sigma^2}{16 f^2} 16 f \sigma \right]
\end{align}
we obtain the divergence of a scale current,
\begin{equation}
     \partial_\mu \mathcal{J}_D^\mu = \Theta_\mu^\mu = -\alpha\left[ -\frac{m_{\sigma}^2}{f} \sigma \right].
\end{equation}

In Litim et. al. 2017 [2], discusses about spontaneous breaking of scale invariance.
References:
[1] Section 2.4 : Hidden scale invariance, Chapter 3: Dilatations, Aspect of symmetry by Sidney Coleman.
[2] Fixed points and the spontaneous breaking of scale invariance
